# Mapstruct + Lombok Builder with only PACKAGE visibility

Tags: lombok, mapstruct

I am struggling with using Mapstruct together with Lombok Builder when the builder has only package visibility.
The target object resizes within the same package as the Mapper. Thus the builder is visible to the mapper. However, the generated mapstruct code picks constructor instead.
If I change the builder visibility to public, then it is picked by the mapper.
I would like to have the same behaviour even for builder with only package visibility. Is that possible?

```
package dto;

@Value
public class CreateDatasetDto {

    private String name;
}
```

```
package dataset;

@Builder(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Data
@Document
public class Dataset {

    @Id
    private String id;   

    private String name;

    @Builder.Default
    private Instant dateCreated = Instant.now();
}
```

```
package dataset;

@Mapper
public interface DatasetMapper {

    Dataset mapCreateDatasetDtoToDomainObject(CreateDatasetDto createDatasetDto);
}
```

Comment: Just to mention, if I remove the builder annotation and add package visible all args. constructor, then this constructor is visible to the Mapstruct and the mapping code is generated. If I change the constructor visibility to private, then the problem is properly reported by Mapstruct. I would expect the same behaviour when using Builder.

Comment: I think it doesn't work because, it's not on the same package, also if you put the target object in the mapper package, the mapper is an interface, and the implementation will be generated on another package.

Comment: Indeed, the mapstruct implementation is generated in the same package as the interface. Moreover, the equivalent works when dealing with contructor - package private constructor IS visible to the mapstruct.